# Could not load type 'System.Web.Mvc.ViewMasterPage<dynamic>'.?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, iis-6, .net-4.0

I am deploying a Asp.Net MVC 2.0 application on IIS 6.0. When I request any page I get the following error.

```
Parser Error Message:
Could not load type 'System.Web.Mvc.ViewMasterPage<dynamic>'.
```

Source Error:

```
Line 1:  <%@ Master Language="C#" Inherits=
                   "System.Web.Mvc.ViewMasterPage<dynamic>" %>

Line 2:  <%@ Import Namespace="Combres.Mvc" %>
Line 3:
```

Source File: /myApp/Views/Shared/Site.Master    Line: 1

```
Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; 
ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.1
```

Comment: do you have a type called dynamic?  You probably need to change that to: `System.Web.Mvc.ViewMasterPage`

Comment: @Martin: dynamic is a valid keyword in .Net 4. The same code works well on IIS 7.0.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

are you missing the Views/web.config file?